# How to restore a DB from a Heroku pg:backups copy

Tags: postgresql, heroku, backup

If I run `heroku pg:backups --app MY_APP`, I see:

```
=== Backups
No backups. Capture one with heroku pg:backups:capture

=== Restores
No restores found. Use heroku pg:backups:restore to restore a backup

=== Copies
ID    Started at                 Status                               Size      From       To
────  ─────────────────────────  ───────────────────────────────────  ────────  ─────────  ───────────
c001  2021-02-23 15:47:54 +0000  Completed 2021-02-23 15:48:27 +0000  509.16KB  From Name  Target Name
```

If I run `heroku pg:backups:info c001 --app MY_APP`, I see:

```
=== Backup c001
Database:         From Name
Started at:       2021-02-23 15:47:54 +0000
Finished at:      2021-02-23 15:48:27 +0000
Status:           Completed
Type:             Manual
Original DB Size: 11.53MB
Backup Size:      509.16KB (96% compression)

=== Backup Logs
```

However, when I try to restore this backup using `heroku pg:backups:restore c001 --app MY_APP`, it tells me that `Backup c001 not found for MY_APP`.

Is there any way I can restore this copy? For context, my database was in the free plan and was deleted by Heroku, so as far as I know this is the last backup I have.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Backups start with b00* and are listed in the top section.
I am not sure what "Copies" are, did not find anything in their docs.

```
❯ heroku pg:backups -r prod
=== Backups
ID    Created at                 Status                               Size      Database
────  ─────────────────────────  ───────────────────────────────────  ────────  ────────
b008  2021-05-04 06:57:18 +0000  Completed 2021-05-04 06:57:20 +0000  664.15KB  DATABASE
b007  2021-05-04 05:33:50 +0000  Completed 2021-05-04 05:33:52 +0000  663.53KB  DATABASE

=== Restores
No restores found. Use heroku pg:backups:restore to restore a backup

=== Copies
ID    Started at                 Status                               Size      From       To
────  ─────────────────────────  ───────────────────────────────────  ────────  ─────────  ───────────
c009  2022-06-23 03:28:14 +0000  Completed 2022-06-23 03:28:46 +0000  232.80KB  From Name  Target Name
c002  2020-05-27 15:29:37 +0000  Completed 2020-05-27 15:29:40 +0000  112.59KB  From Name  Target Name
c001  2020-05-26 19:43:26 +0000  Completed 2020-05-26 19:43:37 +0000  112.97KB  From Name  Target Name
```

```
❯ heroku pg:backups:restore c009 --app <app>
 ▸    Backup c009 not found for ⬢ <app>
```

```
❯ heroku pg:backups:restore b008 --app <app>
 ▸    WARNING: Destructive Action
 ▸    This command will affect the app <app>
 ▸    To proceed, type <app> or re-run this command with --confirm
 ▸    <app>
...
```